# Как искать json объекты по частичному совпадени в laravel и pgsql

Tags: php, json, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

На данный момент я имею такой код

```
$productInfo = ProductInfo::query()
            ->where('site_id', $site->id)
            ->where('field_name', 'ILIKE', $field['field_name'] . '%')
            ->whereJsonContains('field_values',  $field['field_values'])
            ->pluck('field_values')
            ->toArray();
```

Мне надо переделать его чтобы он искал вхождения json с помощью like, перерыл весь инет, чего-то рабочего найти не смог.
Массивы объекты имеют вид.

```
["894","141"]
["351","678","723","728","858","866","868","891","894"]
["TRUE"]

["METRO CHEF","\u0421\u0412\u042f\u0422\u041e\u0419 \u0418\u0421\u0422\u041e\u0427\u041d\u0418\u041a","\u0411\u041e\u0420\u0416\u041e\u041c\u0418","THRON"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось так:

```
$productInfo = DB::table(function ($query) use ($site, $field) {
            $query->selectRaw('json_array_elements_text(field_values) as field_values')
                ->from('product_info')
                ->where('site_id', $site->id)
                ->where('field_name', $field['field']);
        }, 'tmp')
            ->where('field_values', $like, '%' . $field['query'] . '%')
            ->pluck('field_values')
            ->toArray();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]